# Use of __libc_init_array call STM32

Tags: c, gcc, linker, stm32

I can see that the assembly startup file of a STM32 project has this instruction : `bl __libc_init_array` that call this function.

But there is no function like this in my project, what is this function, what is this init, and is it really essential ?

I've noticed that if i compile with the -nostartfiles argument i've a linker error with _init() method not found, could you explain me why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is the function which initialises the standard
 library. You should not touch it unless you know what you are doing.

If you do not link the startup you do not have it and linker throws this error.

But I repeat all that options are for the advanced programmers.

Comment: The c standard library is embedded into my stm32 processor really ? That's weird not ?

Comment: No. If you do not use any functions from the library almost nothing will be linked. But it seems very unlikely that you will not. All the memcpy, strlen and another ones are there. If you not want to use them you will have to write everything yourself